# Finding the average repeats in a binary sequence

Tags: excel, sequence, repeat

I'm having trouble describing this question so here is an example:

Let's say I have a binary sequence in excel with each number in its own row:

10110100111011

I'd like to figure out the average repeat length.

So for the 1's in this example we have: 1,2,1,3,2 (Avg: 1.8)

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a formula or VBA macro?

If VBA macro then **here is the code below**. You can always make an UDF if a regular Excel function is needed:

```
Sub TestBin()
    x = AvgBin("111001110") 'Returns 3
End Sub
Function AvgBin(binString As String)
    Dim count As Integer, arr() As Integer, first As Boolean
    first = True
    ReDim arr(0 To 0)
    For i = 1 To Len(binString)
     If CInt(Mid(binString, i, 1)) = 1 Then
      count = count + 1
     Else
      If first And count > 0 Then
       arr(UBound(arr)) = count
       first = False
       Else
        If count > 0 Then
         ReDim Preserve arr(0 To UBound(arr) + 1)
         arr(UBound(arr)) = count
        End If
      End If
      count = 0
     End If
    Next i
    If count > 0 Then
       arr(UBound(arr)) = count
       count = 0
    End If

    Dim sum As Integer
    For i = 0 To UBound(arr)
      sum = sum + arr(i)
    Next i

    AvgBin = sum / (UBound(arr) + 1)
End Function
```

Comment: This works but all of the numbers have to be in the same cell. I have them all separated in different cells.

Comment: How are they distributed then? In separate cells in rows, columns or how else?

Answer (score 0):

Consider this small macro:

```
Sub dural()
    st = "10110100111011"
    Dim zum As Double, kount As Double
    Dim av As Double
    ary = Split(st, "0")

    zum = 0
    kount = 0
    For Each a In ary
        If a <> "" Then
            zum = zum + Len(a)
            kount = kount + 1
        End If
    Next a

    av = zum / kount
    MsgBox av
End Sub
```